# Leaflet-Draw: Get polygon latLng in 'draw:editvertex' event

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geojson, leaflet.draw

When a `draw:editvertex` event fires, how can I get information about the polygon which triggered it?

```
this.map.on('draw:editvertex', function (e) { debugger;
    var layers = e.layers;
    // I want to get current polygon latLng here
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach works for me (but doesn't feel like best practice) –

In my `draw:editvertex` handler I loop through the `target._layers` and look for the `edited` property:

```
map.on('draw:editvertex', function(e) {
    for (thisLayer in e.target._layers) {
        if (e.target._layers.hasOwnProperty(thisLayer)) {
            if (e.target._layers[thisLayer].hasOwnProperty("edited")) {
                console.log("we think we found the polygon?");
                console.log(e.target._layers[thisLayer]);

                // the updated Polygon array points are here:
                newPolyLatLngArray = e.target._layers[thisLayer].editing.latlngs[0];
            }
        }
    };
});
```

...like I said, this doesn't feel Awesome, but it is working for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are not only `layers` in `e`, but also the target layer `poly` can be approached easily.

```
map.on('draw:editvertex', function (e) { 
  var poly = e.poly;
  var latlngs = poly.getLatLngs(); // here the polygon latlngs
});
```